How to make several charts with the same echartsInstance using timeline?
I'm using timeline with echarts. I need to add more charts to the screen, however, using only one instance of echarts (echarts.init only once). I need to put other charts separate from timeline on the screen, I tried putting a type:“gauge” but it doesn't work:


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Exemplo de Gráfico com Timeline e Gauge</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #chart {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="chart"></div>
    
    <script>
        const chartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));
    
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            chartUse.resize();
        });
    
        const option = {
            baseOption: {
                timeline: {
                    axisType: 'category',
                    autoPlay: true,
                    playInterval: 2000,
                    rewind: false,
                    data: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar']
                },
                grid: {
                    width: "40%",
                    height: "50%",
                    left: "5%"
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "category",
                    data: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar"],
                    gridIndex: 0
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: "value",
                    gridIndex: 0
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        // Gauge fixo, sempre visível
                        type: "gauge",
                        center: ['75%', '50%'], // Posiciona o gauge à direita
                        radius: '30%',
                        detail: { formatter: '{value}%' },
                        data: [{ value: 50, name: 'Progress' }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: [
                // Opção 1: Gráfico de barras para janeiro
                {
                    series: [
                        {
                            type: "bar",
                            xAxisIndex: 0,
                            yAxisIndex: 0,
                            data: [10, 20, 30]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                // Opção 2: Gráfico de barras para fevereiro
                {
                    series: [
                        {
                            type: "bar",
                            xAxisIndex: 0,
                            yAxisIndex: 0,
                            data: [15, 25, 35]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                // Opção 3: Gráfico de barras para março
                {
                    series: [
                        {
                            type: "bar",
                            xAxisIndex: 0,
                            yAxisIndex: 0,
                            data: [20, 30, 40]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
    
        chartUse.setOption(option);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
     



In other words, using just one instance (chartUse) I need to place other charts using the timeline in this same instance. How can I adjust baseOption and options to achieve this result?

It's unclear how you want to set up the other sub-chart. You already set a grid, which is the way to go if you want to group multiple charts in one chart instance. What is missing to have the gauge shown is to give it a grid entry too, and also to add the bar chart in the baseOption.series, see fiddle.

As it is mentioned already, you can use grid property to achieve that https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid
